# Issues with Auto Login using Request

Tags: python, python-3.x

newbie here trying to get a hang of python.

I am trying to do a autologin to the following form:

```
<form method='get' action='/459878994660274374406314699062505324297/login'>
<table><tr><td> 
    Username: 
</td><td>
<input type='text' name='uid'>
</td></tr><tr><td>
    Password:
</td><td>
<input type='password' name='pw'>
</td></tr><tr><td></td><td align='right'>
<input type='submit' value='Login'>
</td></tr></table>
</form>
```

I extracted the fields for username and password respectively which is "uid" and "pw". I used the following code :

```
import requests
url = 'https://googlegruyere.appspot.com/459878994660274374406314699062505324297/login'
values = {'uid': 'abc',
          'pw': 'abcd'}

r = s.post(url, data=values)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.history)
print(r.content)
print(r.url)
```

Reviewing the r.url and r.conten, the login neither failed or succeed as it is still response with the same page before the post command.

Did i miss something ? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there are some headers you are missing ? You can check the network requests/responses in the console (F12 in chrome). There will be some headers, cookies and other stuff that is maybe important to the backend.

Comment: The `<form` uses `method='get'` instead of `post`.